# open in Eclipse - Code

Tags: android

how can I open the example code from this page FragmentBasics.zip ([developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)) in Eclipse?

If i try i becam the error [2012-04-30 12:59:11 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\dev\FragmentBasics\AndroidManifest.xml: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Eclipse Version: 3.7.1

Thanks
Bobert

Comment: Please copy/paste stack trace here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your Manifest.xml. This exception generally relates to white/trailing spaces or incorrect xml format. 
Try looking using Altova/XML editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by editing the file AndroidManifest.xml and moving the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` above the copywrite comment:

```
<!--
Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
```

It seems that the parser needs to read the `<?xml` tag at the beginning of the file. I've filed a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30505&thanks=30505&ts=1336503159

In conclusion, your AndroidManifest.xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.fragments"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Once the project has been imported, you will have to fix the same problem in the other xml files in the project (res/layout/article_view.xml, res/layout/news_articles.xml, res/layout-large/news_articles.xml, and res/values/strings.xml).

I found that the package that eclipse created in the src/ directory was called com.example.fragments instead of com.examples.android.fragments. I don't know why that happens, but I fixed it by clicking the error message at the package declaration for each file and selecting: Move 'FILENAME.java' to package 'com.example.android.fragments'.

Lastly, I had to import android.os.Build in HeadlinesFragment.java to get the project to compile and run.